# Universal button handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a lot of buttons on my web app that request and post data to PHP to retrieve and update a database. I am struggling to create a universal way to prevent multiple button clicks when submitting forms, because I am using AJAX and Jquery.

This is my current implementation but I can't even tell if it works. It seems to work 99% of the time.

In my common functions.js file I have this function which is in the global scope

```
var canClick = true;

function buttonWithPromise(promise){
    if(!canClick) return;
    canClick = false;
    promise.done(function(){
        canClick = true;
    });
}
```

Then any time I attach a .click to a dom element I do it like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.table > .row', function(){
    var nbr = $(this).attr('nbr');  
    buttonWithPromise(get_count(nbr));
});
```

And some function that might be called will have a deferred object.

```
function get_count(){
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var options = "getCount"
    Query.init(options)
        .fetchData(function(data){   //Ajax data request
            if(data){
            }
            defer.resolve();
    });
    return defer.promise();
}
```

Since this only sometimes works, I can tell it's wrong. Any advice for improvements?

Comment: Please define the key problem you're having so that someone can help you.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. It only works sometimes. For example, if I click something that requests a list of data and I don't get it right away, I will get that data as fast as I can click. I am trying to prevent that, but it only seems to work some of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Javascript is an object, yes? So why not:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function()
{
    // Set default value of property
    if(typeof this.isClicked === 'undefined')
        this.isClicked = false;

    // Check if button is working
    if(this.isClicked)
    {
        // Send error to console if button is busy
        console.log('Cannot click as a network action is occuring!');
    }else
    {
        // Begin new network action if button is not busy
        var self = this;

        console.log('Begin network for: ' + $(this).text());
        this.isClicked = true;

        setTimeout(function()
                   {
                       // Reset button state once network action is done
                       console.log('End network for: ' + $(self).text());
                       self.isClicked = false;

                       //Call any callbacks/promises here
                   }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mdLfug1t/

NOTE: I'm using setTimeout to simulate an ajax request

EDIT: Let me put this more into context:

```
function buttonWithPromise(promise)
{
    if(typeof promise.canClick === 'undefined')
        promise.canClick = true;

    if(!promise.canClick) return;

    promise.canClick = false;

    promise.done(function()
    {
        promise.canClick = true;
    });
}
```

The problem that you're running into is that "canClick" is global and so gets modified by every promise. You need to make it a property of a promise so that you can create infinite promises, each with their own instance of canClick.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this out